# Loop an object to get index values

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Hi i have an object in the following format, I need to loop through it to get the image urls.

```
original = {
    '0': 'http://amt.in/img/logo.png',
    '1': 'http://amt.in/img/slide/2.png',
    '2': 'http://amt.in/img/gallery/1.jpg', 
    options: {
        withDomLvl1: true,
        normalizeWhitespace: false,
        xmlMode: false,
        decodeEntities: true
    },
}
```

I have tried this

```
 for (var key in original) {
                if (original.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    console.log(key + " -> " + original[key]);
                }
            }
```

Is there any better way using underscore js or lodash

Comment: What is the definition of "better"? Better is subjective.  What is the issue with your solution?

Comment: but what about the `options` key @Michael? perfectly reasonable to have numeric keys in an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
urls = _.filter(original, function(v, k) {
    return !isNaN(k)
})
```